# How are limits outside an exceptional set defined?

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

In some contexts one encounters statements like:

The following equation is true
$$
f(x) = o(g(x)),
$$
when $x\to\infty$ outside of an exceptional set $E$ of such and such measure.

My interpretation is that the statement above means that there exists a set $E$ of such and such measure, such that
$$
f|_{E^\complement}(x) = o(g(x)),
$$
where $x\to\infty$. Is this accurate?

Comment: Yes this is accurate. This is where the idea of almost everywhere comes from